# ob_start() usage in wrapping entire project

Tags: php, ob-start

I've started working for a new company, who to my surprise run their projects like this

```
<?php
//at start of project
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
//all project data
```

This surprised me because I plan my projects in such a way where PHP Post and other such data is run first, then I include HTML content after i.e.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  //do post stuff
}
checkUserLoggedIn(); //other such functions that need to be run before headers sent

//then include html content
include "htmlheader.php";
```

This way, I never have issues with headers already sent etc, however with the ob_start(); at the start of the application, header redirects still work.

Short and simple question, is using ob_start(); at the top of the entire project an acceptable use of the function or should it be avoided?

Comment: Meh. If you're doing it to avoid *headers already sent* errors, you're simply doing it wrong. If you're doing it to gzip the response, as seems the case here... it's legit, but I'd rather delegate that task to the web server instead. So... meh.

Comment: +1 to @deceze, especially when considering that the webserver (well, at least for Apache) does it neatly when correctly configured.

Comment: NGinX rocks for gzip'ing too. It fires out HTML and compressed HTML like bullets

Comment: Also, if you do things right the entire application should have exactly one `echo` statement. Making sure nothing else gets sent to the browser is then pretty easy.